# Java NullPointerException error with making an array of user-defined class and initializing it

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

In the following code can anyone tell the error?

```
public class Person {
    int age;
    String name;
}

public class Enter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Enter ob = new Enter();
        Person p[] = new Person[5];

        p[0].name = "abc"; //Line 13
        p[0].age = 67;
            //I have initialized the whole array likewise.
    }
}
```

But in line 13 it gives the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at Enter.main(SorAccToAge.java:13)

Comment: I recommend not to use this style, it is bad OOP.

Answer (score 5):

`Object` types are `null` by default in Java. Elements in an Object array are no different. Ensure elements of the array are initialized prior to assigning values to their fields

```
for (int i=0; i < p.size(); i++) {
  p[i] = new Person();
}
```

Comment: Off topic: I suggest using setter methods for assigning values instead, namely [encapsulation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
Person p[] = new Person[5];
```

will simply init an array with null values, so you have to init items with:

```
Person p[] = new Person[5];

    p[0] = new Person();
    p[1] = new Person();
```

and so on or, in a single instruction

```
Person p[] = new Person[5] = {
  new Person(),new Person(),new Person(),new Person(),new Person()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize any of the objects in that array.

so you could use for loop to do so,

```
Person p[] = new Person[5];
for(int i=0; i<p.size(); i++){
  p[i] = new Person();
}

p[0].name = "abc"; //Line 13
p[0].age = 67;

p[1].name = "xyz"; //Line 13
p[1].age = 68;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create an array of objects, each object in the array is not initialized.
An individual element would look like this:

```
Person example;
```

Obviously, "example" isn't initialized yet, so the pointer is null, and no object has been constructed. To solve this, just initialize p[0] like so:

```
p[0] = new Person();
```

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Enter ob = new Enter();
    Person p[] = new Person[5];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
       p[i] = new Person();
    }
    p[0].name = "abc"; //Line 13
    p[0].age = 67;
            //I have initialized the whole array likewise.
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that your array has been initialized but the elements in the array has not.

If you make your `Person` class immutable it will be even more clear to you:

```
public final class Person {
    private final int age;
    private final String name;

    public Person(int age, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Now you will see that you cannot even call `p[0].name = "abc"`. And there is no setter so you cannot even do `p[0].setName("abc")`.

Each record must be initialized like this instead:

```
p[0] = new Person(67, "abc");
```

Although you would still get a NPE if you do `p[0].getName()` on an uninitialized array element.

So to conclude, you must initialize each element of the array after the array has been created.

Answer (score 0):

```
Person p[] = new Person[5];
```

above statement create p[] array with null values

so before use instantiate of p, like

```
p[0]=new Person();
```

like this you need to initialize the array before using